# Laravel Route group and prefix

Tags: laravel

Info: I'm using Larvel Version 6.1.0 and I want my website to support different languages. Therefore I created a new middleware and wanted to give my routes a prefix so Laravel can determine the languages.Maybe there's a better way but here's what I did so far.

The urls are supposed to look like this in the end:

mywebsite.com/en/home , url/locale/home

---

The middleware to set the locale

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

Registered the new middleware setlocale in kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'setlocale' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
    ];
```

---

My web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['setlocale'],'prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function() {

Route::get('/', 'NewController@frontpage');
Route::get('/home', 'NewController@frontpage')->name("home");

Auth::routes();

});
```

---

For some reason the prefix part in my route group isn't working at all. When I enter mywebsite.com/en/home in my browser I get

> Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {locale}/login]

Which is strange because I didn't request the login route but the home route and I passed a locale.
Does anyone see the error or has a better idea to implement support for several languages in Laravel Version 6 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to take the `Auth::routes()` outside route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['setlocale'],'prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function() {

    Route::get('/', 'NewController@frontpage');
    Route::get('/home', 'NewController@frontpage')->name("home");

});


Auth::routes();
```

The issue is being caused as the `{locale}` prefix is being prepended to the `/login` route (and all other auth routes).

Comment: Was this after visit `/home` or `/en/home`

Comment: It was the Auth::routes() after all. The second error message came up because I had to change this inside a view {{route('home')}} to {{route('home',app()->getlocale())}} Problem solved , thank you.

Comment: After visitng /en/home .